# Understanding different parameters passed to Contacts.getContactsAsync in expo-contacts react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, android-contacts

I am using expo-contacts in react-native to get contact details. I just got started and kind of copy-pasted the code used to do so. Everything is working fine but i am not understanding the params passed to `Contacts.getContactsAsync({pageSize: 1, offset: 0, fields: ['PHONE_NUMBER']})`.

Please explain `pageSize` (which i understood a little. I think pageSize is used to get a particular number of contacts), `offset` and `fields` (i think `fields` is a filtering method, but not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh just after some minutes of asking this question, now i got these.

Here are the details;

```
fields >> If available the fields defined will be returned. If nil then all fields will be returned.

pageSize >> The max number of contacts to return. If nil or 0 then all contacts will be returned.

offset >> The number of contacts to skip before gathering contacts.
```

More details here;

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/#contactquery